# Does having permissions to SELECT and View Definition on a schema give you special permissions on that schema's database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, database-schema, sql-view

My colleague has performed a strange form of magic that has revealed my ignorance. He has made a schema containing views, `[VW_COLLEAGUE]` and given users the permission to SELECT and View Definition on anything in that schema. On that same database, another schema exists, `[SECRET]`. Users do not have any permissions on that schema. Yet, when my colleague has done this

```
CREATE VIEW [VW_COLLEAGUE].[REVEAL_SECRET] AS
SELECT *
FROM [SECRET].[SECRET_TABLE]
```

the users can query that view just fine despite having no power to query the table. One notable property of his `[VW_COLLEAGUE]` views is that all of them only reference the database to which `[VW_COLLEAGUE]` belongs. I tried to repeat his trick with a query that referenced multiple databases, but my users were treated like they did not have permission. This gives me three deeply related questions:

1. Why does my colleagues' trick work?
2. Is my colleagues' trick intended behavior?
3. Why does referencing multiple databases break it?

Note: I'm very open to the possibility that I'm extremely ignorant. I'm notoriously bad with permissions.

Comment: This is called "ownership chaining". The users have permission to `SELECT` on the view `[VW_COLLEAGUE].[REVEAL_SECRET]` and that and the object `[SECRET].[SECRET_TABLE]` have the same owner; as such users inherit a `SELECT` permission on the table when referencing the `VIEW` with a `SELECT`.

Comment: By default, ownership chaining is only relevant to objects in the same database. Cross Database Chaining is a feature, however, it comes with a wealth of caveats and security considerations which is well beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Larnu Interesting, I've taken a very close look at my colleague's code and he's somehow managed to do what I was wanted to do - i.e. what you expected to be cross-database ownership chaining - without enabling it or doing any special permissions/certificates/impersonation tricks. This is likely turning in to an entirely separate question, but do you have any how that could've been done? It's as if making a view in one database lets him use that view in other databases when making new views.

Comment: For ownership chaining cross database it *must* be enabled; either at the server or databases. Otherwise you would be using signed procedures, or the `LOGIN` has a mapped `USER` in the other database with the needed permissions.

Comment: @Larnu You're on the brink of giving me the answer to my original question. I know that the procedures aren't signed and that cross-database ownership chaining is not enabled. However, the `LOGIN`s and `USERS`s are identical in every database. Are views and permissions on them somehow specially treated in such a case? The trick seems to be something to do with views referencing views.

Comment: You already answered your own question; the `LOGON` has `USER`s in all the databases that can `SELECT` on the `VIEW`s. Though note that nested `VIEW`s can perform poorly.

Comment: @Larnu That's probably it. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Larnu Your comments on this question have saved the day for me again. Your final comment was totally correct. Again, feel free to post this as an answer.